# Colours of the android app changes whenever I switch to dark mode on my mobile

Tags: android

I am using android studio 4.1. And android version on my physical phone is 10. When I install the app on my phone, the colours that I see on my phone and the colours that are there in the project are very different. I found that whenever I switch off the dark mode on my phone, the colours become same as they are in the project. And whenever I switch to dark mode on my phone, the colours change. I only want the colours which are displayed in light mode on my phone, in both the cases, if dark mode is off or isn't.
And one more thing, i am not finding styles.xml in res/values and something like res(generated) is also in the project/app, these are the things which I do not find generally in any project...

Screenshot of [values/themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6keC6.png!).

Screenshot of [app in light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD1XO.jpg).

Screenshot of [app in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb8iK.jpg).

Screenshot of [Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mflOX.png)(in which some things are there that I do not found generally in any project and styles.xml is also not there).

Screenshot of [AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXtwA.png)..

If you want more information to solve this problem, please comment.

**Please help**

Comment: In order to get help you'll need to be more clear in your question and provide more details and code. Your app is likely using a base theme like Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight or Theme.AppCompat.DayNight, which would explain why its switching colors when the device mode is changed.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

Comment: CSmith , so what should I do to stop this? The colour changing in different modes... How do I stop this?

Comment: I have amended my answer to show how you should define your application theme, please review

Answer (score 3):

You have used `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` as your app theme parent, changing this to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` will change your app to a light theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Calculator" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, found in the manifests folder of your Android Studio workspace, please ensure you're referencing your **Theme.Calculator** theme.

```
<application ... android:theme="@style/Theme.Calculator" ...>
```

You should consider leaving the "DayNight" based theme and add a `colors.xml` to your `res/values-night` folder.  This would allow you to define alternative colors for dark theme, then your app could look great in both dark and light themes.

Learn more about styles and themes at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.

Comment: CSmith, nothing changed when I changed Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar. And where is values-night? I didn't find it is res..

Comment: make sure your app manifest has android:theme="@style/Theme.Calculator" on the <application> tag

Comment: CSmith, colors.xml is already there and  <application ... android:theme="@style/Theme.Calculator" ...> , is also in the Android Manifest file . I want that my app look same in both the themes. What should I do?  Previously i was making a app in android studio 4.0 and that app's colours didn't changed whether I used it in light mode or dark mode....But in 4.1 version the colours are changing but in this app they are changing . I am fed up with this ☹☹. Please help ...

Comment: I have added screenshot of AndroidManifest.xml also ..

Comment: as described in my answer, in your styles.xml change the parent of Theme.Calculator to "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: It's already there. But now I solved the problem. Thanku so much for your support

Comment: please mark my answer as Accepted, thanks

Comment: @JaiSoni How you fixed this. I am having similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing the same problem and finally find a solution that works over Android 29(Android Q). Some UI's such as MIUI force dark mode that's why they tend to change colors and drawables even some lottie files.

Apply this piece of code into your custom theme;

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution, the same thing happened to me, the chorus of the text of my buttons is white but when I activated the night mode of the cell phone they changed to blue, then I discovered that it is because the default buttons have the white color for the text and I didn't do anything, but even so you have to define a color for them, so I went down to where it says textcolor and I put the color that was @color/white and that's it, that was it, I hope it helps you. Sorry for the bad English I use a translator